# set backgroung image from resources

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, background-image

I have a view which has a method `setBackgroundImage(BitmapDrawable)` and I have an image `imgbg` in drawable folder in res.

How do I set this image as background image?

`view.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.imgbg);` doesn't work as `R.drawable.imgbg` is an integer but method requires drawable.

I know it's silly thing but I'm not able sort it out even after intensive googling.

Any help appreciated.

### Edit

This code snippet doesn't belong to Activity class so I don't have `context` object or `getResources()` or `getApplicationContext()`...

### Edit 2 (Solution):

```
public class PieChartDemo01View extends View 
{
public PieChartDemo01View(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    Drawable drawable = super.getResources().getDrawable(
        R.drawable.bg2);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;

}
}
```

Comment: Simple use this link and paste me your code http://pastie.org/4795861 i see and say what the problem.

Comment: use this solved code and running code dear .http://pastie.org/5492255

Comment: then Dear Flag this pastig code it`s helpful to some one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple First get drawable then set cast in bitmapDrawable.

```
Drawable drawable=getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgbg);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable=(BitmapDrawable) drawable;
```

Just Do it Dear It`s work.

Comment: This code snippet doesn't belong to Activity class so I don't have access to `getApplicationContext()`...

Comment: then Simple dear just change the getApplicationContext() to context.which you pass here.

Answer (score 2):

```
view.setBackgroundImage(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgbg))
```

Comment: This code snippet doesn't belong to Activity class so I don't have access to `getResources()`...

Comment: You have to pass activity/context from the caller, and then you can have context.getResources()......

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgbg);
```

Updated :

```
Drawable imgbg = context.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.imgbg );
view.setBackgroundImage(imgbg);
```

Comment: view is object of `PiePlot` which **ONLY** have `setBackgroundImage(BitmapDrawable)` method. It doesn't have `setImageResource(R.drawable.imgbg)`...

Comment: This code snippet doesn't belong to `Activity` class so I don't have context object...

Comment: It seems you are having context passed in your constructor `public PieChartDemo01View(Context context) ` so you can use that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Drawable by resource id and use it in your methods:

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgbg)
```

Comment: This code snippet doesn't belong to `Activity` class so I don't have context object...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgbg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps changing it to

`BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.imgbg))
setBackgroundImage(background);`

That should be able to work.

Comment: This code snippet doesn't belong to Activity class so I don't have access to `getResources()`...